# Thunderbird takes 5+ min to start up

Tags: thunderbird, anti-virus

Since upgrading to Thunderbird 91 (currently 91.7.0), it consistently takes 5+ minutes to start [Windows 10 Pro x64 v. 21H2], even in Troubleshooting Mode (all extensions disabled). I can see the Disk Active time pegged at 100% in the Task Manager during this time, with little to no CPU usage. I thought my antivirus might be doing some odd scan on the profile folder, but I uninstalled F-Secure Security Suite for AV (rebranded for Spectrum) and that didn't change anything. I set up a Microsoft Defender Antivirus scan Exclusion (Windows Security -> Virus & threat protection -> Virus & threat protection settings -> Manage settings -> Exclusions -> Add or remove exclusions) for my TB profile folder, but that didn't do anything either. I have a heavily-customized profile with 6 email accounts, so I really don't want to have to create another profile, but I guess I will if it comes to that... Any other ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Are you saving the emails to disk (POP3) or using IMAP?

Comment: @Ramhound all accounts use IMAP, with basically everything locally cached.

Comment: Mechanical or SSD? These fairly large mailboxes?

Comment: @Ramhound SSD - 1 mailbox is particularly large - %profile%\ImapMail\ is 4.3GB

Comment: Have you tried performing a [compact](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/compacting-folders) on your messages?

Comment: @Ramhound Tb is already set to auto-compact

Comment: Does Thunderbird provide an easy way to disable a mailbox temporarily? The idea is to determine if it’s a specific mailbox causing the delay

Comment: @Ramhound It is only possible to disable checking for messages at startup. The only method I could think of is backing up the profile and deleting the accounts each by each. Afterwards restore the profile backup.